# Error when trying to run AVD

Tags: android, device, virtual

When i'm launching the AVD, this error this showing.

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'andDev' qemu-system-armel.exe: -drive index=2,id=system,file=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk/system-images\android-15\default\armeabi-v7a\/system.img: 
could not open disk image C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk/system-images\android-15\default\armeabi-v7a\/system.img: 
Could not open 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk/system-images\android-15\default\armeabi-v7a\/system.img': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

I too was facing the same issue...

Came across this: https://serverfault.com/questions/525694/qemu-system-x86-64w-exe-could-not-open-disk-image-d-img-img-permission-denie:

> QEMU must have write permissions to the disk image, otherwise it
>   complains with "Permission denied" error. The solution is to mark the
>   file writable by unchecking the "read-only" box at the file
>   properties.

You'll need to also give the write permissions to the `system.img` file(s) used by the AVD for the user account.

Worked for me!